# Standalone ATmega168, powered by 4xAA batteries

Tags: batteries, schematics, breadboard, atmega

I'm making a small animating diorama as a present.  There is a switch, two servos, and an LED; all being powered by four AA batteries and all controlled by an ATmega168 chip.  I've prototyped the simple stuff on my arduino uno, but now I want to move the ATmega chip and hook up the battery pack, both of which are new to me.

I'm too new to the site to post any inline images, or for some of the links to be completely valid.  I apologize in advance.

This is the design I put together in Frizting:

- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3144073/diorama/breadboard.pdf
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3144073/diorama/schema.pdf

I've used these two articles as reference (remove the spaces):

- http://www.tkk.fi/Misc/Electronics/circuits/psu_5v.html
- http://www.instructables.com/id/Standalone-Arduino-ATMega-chip-on-breadboard

I would be very surprised if I had it all wired up correctly. I'd be very grateful if anyone could comment on what I've done wrong.

PS.  The software polls the state of the toggle switch.  If the switch is on, it sets the two servos to specific values, and turns on the LED.  If the switch is off, it sets the servos to difference values, and turns off the LED.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that 4*AA are the problem. You're using 7805 for regulation and your soruce is going to give you at most 6.4 V, but will quickly drop to around 6. You need at least 2 V higher intput voltage to use 7805, so you won't be getting 5 V at the output and AT won't start.

Also, 7805 will waste some power. If you can, try to find another way of getting the needed 5 V.

I'm not sure about the rest of it. There could be other errors too.

Answer (score 2):

The Atmegas are rated to 5.5V. I have run PICs on 6.5V with no problems, but I did not test them for a long time, nor did I verify they met all their specs. I suppose if it was a little toy, you could try using a diode to drop about 0.5V, this way the voltage will always be under 6V, which should be okay.

Comment: +1 on using a diode to drop the voltage. A lot of AVRs will run all the way down to 1.6V, too, and all of them will run at 3.6 volts, so it may not matter if he drops even more. The servos' voltage range would be the limitation. I like using 4 1.2V NiMH batteries to get about 5V but a gift would have to be more robust.